# page validation not working in jquery mobile after ajax request

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating an android application using jquery mobile which is a single page app where all the pages  lie in the same file `index.html`in the following manner:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_id1" data-dom-cache="false">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> 
    //content
</div> 
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page_id2" data-dom-cache="false">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> 
     //content
</div> 
</div>
```

I have used jquery.validation.js (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for validating the text fields on every page using keyup and blur event in the following manner:

```
var PAGE = {

        login : "#page_id1",
        registration: "#page_id2",
        home:"#page_id3",

        getCurrentId : function(){
            return $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' );
        }
}



var FORM = {

     validate: function (formid, buttonid) {

        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~RULES~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            $(formid).validate({
                rules : {

                    maxLength : 30,

                    login_textbox_email : {
                        required : true,
                        email : true,

                    },

                    login_textbox_password : {
                        required : true,
                        minlength : 6,

                    },


                }
            });

        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~RULES END~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


            if ($(formid).valid()) {

                $(buttonid).prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $(buttonid).prop('disabled', 'disabled');

            };


        }
}

$('input').on('blur keyup', function() {

    var currentPage = '#' + PAGE.getCurrentId();
    var _button_id;
    var _form_id;

    if (currentPage == PAGE.login) {
        _button_id = '#login_btn_login_user';
        _form_id = '#form_index';
    }

    FORM.validate(_form_id, _button_id);
});
```

and its working fine,
but when I try to authenticate the user using restful service, my login page refreshes automatically in the background (in case of  unsuccessful login/ajax request failure) and the validations are no more available on the fields i.e. keyup and blur events show no effect on the page and the button on the page which is expected to be disabled till all the fields are validated also gets enabled.

Can somebody please guide, why is it happening and how it can be fixed.

Comment: If you're using ajax to replace the form, the input elements get replaced and the events get removed. Could you try `$(document).on('blur keyup', 'input', function() {` ? *(Edited)*

Comment: @TylerY86 Tried, but didn't worked.

Comment: `FORM` and `PAGE` may need to be updated to. If the `FORM` is replaced, and it's a jquery validation object, it may need to be reinitialized. I don't know what `PAGE` is.

Comment: @TylerY86 I have updated the code, please have a look

Comment: if the `currentPage` is not `PAGE.login` then are `_button_id` and `_form_id` supposed to be left `undefined`? (e.g. they cause `FORM.validate(_form_id, _button_id)` to be `FORM.validate(undefined,undefined)`, causing it to fail)

Comment: @TylerY86 No, there are other values as well, I haven't included it to keep the example short